# How to move the window controls to the left when using Compiz on XFCE?

Tags: linux-mint, xfce, window-manager, compiz

I'm using Linux Mint 18 with XFCE. When using XFCE window manager I can configure it to put the window controls (close, minimize, maximize) in the left of the title bar (OSX style). But once I change the Window Manager to Compiz, the window controls are moved to the right and I can't find a way to move them to the left.